# Setting same SelectedIndex value for multiple combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a form where i have 23 `Comboboxes`. Writing `SelectedIndex=-1` for every combobox will definitely work  but i want to know whether there's any other way of doing it as done in below given example. ?

```
  For Each ctl As Control In (GroupBox1.Controls)
            If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
                ctl.Text = ""
            End If            
 Next
```

i tried this,
`If TypeOf ctl Is ComboBox Then
  ctl.selectedIndex=-1
   End If` 
but it doesn't works. Please help me out.

Comment: In which way it doesn't work? Do you have all your combobox inside the same container? (A groupbox, a panel, the form iteself)

Comment: All the combos are in contained in a groupbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example your `ctl` variable is a `Control` and not a `Combobox` so it does not have the `SelectIndex` property - though you could have casted it back with `DirectCast(ctl, Combobox)`.

```
For Each ctl As Control In (GroupBox1.Controls)
  If TypeOf ctl Is Combobox Then
    DirectCast(ctl, Combobox).SelectedIndex = -1
  End If            
Next
```

Or create a loop of type specific control for your loop. No need to check type here.

```
Dim cbs = GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of Combobox)()
For Each cb In cbs
 cb.SelectedIndex = -1
Next
```